# second memcpy() attaches previous memcpy() array to it

Tags: c, memcpy

I have a little problem here with `memcpy()`

When I write this

```
char ipA[15], ipB[15];
size_t b = 15;
memcpy(ipA,line+15,b);
```

It copies `b` bytes from array `line` starting at 15th element (fine, this is what i want)

```
memcpy(ipB,line+31,b);
```

This copies `b` bytes from line starting at 31st element, **but** it also attaches to it the result for previous command i.e `ipA`.

Why? `ipB` size is 15, so it shouldnt have enough space to copy anything else. whats happening here?

- result for `ipA` is `192.168.123.123`
- result for `ipB` becomes `205.123.123.122 192.168.123.123`

Where am I wrong? I dont actually know alot about memory allocation in C.

Comment: When working with C arrays, you should always keep track of their size and the length of their content in separate variables. A very good idea is using some struct t_array{size_t allocated; size_t legth; size_t element_size; void data} and a bunch of helper functions/macros to manipulate it.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're not null-terminating the string in ipA.  The compiler has put the two variables next to one another in memory, so string operations assume that the first null terminator is sometime after the second array (whenever the next `0` occurs in memory).

Try:

```
char ipA[16], ipB[16];
size_t b = 15;
memcpy(ipA,line+15,b);
ipA[15] = '\0';
memcpy(ipB,line+31,b);
ipB[15] = '\0';
printf("ipA: %s\nipB: %s\n", ipA, ipB)
```

This should confirm whether this is the problem.  Obviously you could make the code a bit more elegant than my test code above.  As an alternative to manually terminating, you could use `printf("%.*s\n", b, ipA);` or similar to force printf to print the correct number of characters.

Comment: There is actually nothing in the OP's post stating that ipA and ipB contains strings, even though it seems highly likely. If they are indeed containing strings, strpcy() could be used instead of memcpy(). strcpy() has the advantage that it most likely gives a major runtime crash if you have forgotten null termination.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, I agree with all of that.  I made the assumption that he/she was working with strings since it looked like that was the problem.  It is perfectly possible that the source strings are not null-terminated but need to be printed: in that case strcpy is not ideal.  If they are certain to be null-terminated then strcpy is a good solution.  The OP mentioned copying bytes, so I was a bit wary of suggesting strcpy...

Comment: @Lundin: `strcpy` is almost always bad, at least make that `strncpy`. Especially given his example code, which refers substrings within a string. In that case, `strcpy` would not yield the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Are you checking the content of the arrays by doing `printf("%s", ipA)` ? If so, you'll end up with the described effect since your array is interpreted as a C string which is not null terminated. Do this instead: `printf("%.*s", sizeof(ipA), ipA)`

Comment: i m writing it into a file aswell, printf("%.*s", sizeof(ipA), ipA) helps in output but when written in file, gives the same problem! how do i null terminate a memcopied array?

Comment: How are you writing to a file ? If you're using `fprintf`, the same technique applies: use `%.*s` (this means: two arguments are supplied, first the size to print, then the string to print which therefor doesn't need to be null terminated). If you're using `write` then you need to pass the correct size anyways...

Answer (score 0):

Character strings in C require a terminating mark. It is the char value `0`.

As your two character strings are contiguous in memory, if you don't terminate the first character string, then when reading it, you will continue until memory contains the end-of-string character.

Comment: i m writing it into a file aswell,  printf("%.*s", sizeof(ipA), ipA) helps in output but when written in file, gives the same problem! how do i null terminate a memcopied array?